# npm install of custom branch fails due to local changes

Tags: node.js, git, github, npm, package.json

I'm quite baffled by the following situation:

1. I forked a git repository, created a new branch, made some changes and pushed to github.
2. I changed the dependency for the package in the `package.json` of a node.js project I'm working on to point to the branch, i.e. `<dependency>: "https://github.com/<myUsername>/<forkedRepo>.git#<branch>"`
3. I execute `npm install`

This results in the following error message:

`npm ERR! git checkout 7275f0542b4efbf72f8faaacd6bec5b8d9b3c1a5: error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by checkout: ...(some files)`

There are two peculiar things about this:

1. Why should an npm install interfere with my local repository?
2. My local repository is clean, i.e. has the same state as the one on github: 

   `git status
   On branch <branchName>
   nothing to commit, working directory clean`

Stuff I already tried: *(unsuccessful)*

- `npm cache clear`
- `npm cache clear -g`
- removed `node_modules` from the node.js project *(and now I can't get it back, because `npm install` fails)*

Does anyone have any ideas on how to resolve this?

Comment: trying removing the node_modules directory from the project that you are trying to install your custom branch to. Just to double check my understanding: You have two projects, and one uses the other, correct?

Comment: Already removed it. I'll update _Stuff I already tried_ to reflect this.
Yeah the situation is:
 
- Project A: node.js app
- Project B: fork of a repo on github which is used by my project
- I adjust Project A's package.json to point to the new branch instead of some version number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a reference to anyone stumbling upon a similar situation:

I resolved my issue by backing up all files I modified in the forked project, deleting the whole branch (locally as well as on github), creating a new branch, pasting in my edits back in and pushing this new branch to github.